# Tab is focusing on my implicitly generated ListBoxItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox that hosts controls.  I would like to be able to tab from one control to a control the next row down.  It appears that the implicitly generated ListBoxItem is getting focus after I hit tab.  How can I get around this ?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding UiControls}" 
         DockPanel.Dock="Top"
         BorderThickness="0"
         Background="{DynamicResource ControlInteriorBrush}"
         KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue"
         KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation="Continue">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="col1"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="col2"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="col3"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Column="0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}" 
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"     
                               Background="{DynamicResource ControlInteriorBrush}"
                               Foreground="{DynamicResource FontBrush}"
                               Margin="0,0,25,0"
                               KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue"/>
                </Border>
                <Controls:AutoCompleteTextBox Default="{Binding Path=DefaultValue}"  
                                              Items="{Binding Path=DropDownValues}"
                                              Tag="{Binding}"
                                              DataContext="{Binding}"
                                              Width="300" 
                                              Grid.Column="1" 
                                              Height="30"
                                              Background="{DynamicResource ControlInteriorBrush}"
                                              Margin="0,0,10,0"
                                              KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True"
                                              FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a ListBox, use an ItemsControl which does not take focus.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UiControls}" >
 ...
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: That did work, but I would like to know how to do it with a ListBox.

Comment: An `ItemsControl` doesn't have a selection while a `ListBox` has. "Downgrading" to an `ItemsControl` may not be an option.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a pattern you can use to allow individual controls in a list box item to participate in tab navigation. I have only included the XAML that is required - you will have to customize this to suit your needs.

```
<ListBox Focusable="False" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

When tabbing into this list box the first focusable control in the first item will receive focus. Tabbing again will move to the next focusable control in the first item, and when there are no more controls, focus (and selection) will move to the next item in the list box. When the last control in the last item is reached tabbing will move to the next control following the list box in the containing element.

Because `ListBoxItem` cannot receive focus you cannot navigate between items in the list using the arrow keys. You will have to implement this in each control inside the `ListBoxItem`.